# When should I use String.Format or String.Concat instead of the concatenation operator?

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

In C# it is possible to concatenate strings in several different ways:

Using the concatenation operator:

```
var newString = "The answer is '" + value + "'.";
```

Using `String.Format`:

```
var newString = String.Format("The answer is '{0}'.", value);
```

Using `String.Concat`:

```
var newString = String.Concat("The answer is '", value, "'.");
```

What are the advantages / disadvantages of each of these methods? When should I prefer one over the others?

The question arises because of a debate between developers. One *never* uses `String.Format` for concatenation - he argues that this is for formatting strings, not for concatenation, and that is is always unreadable because the items in the string are expressed in the wrong order. The other *frequently* uses `String.Format` for concatenation, because he thinks it makes the code easier to read, especially where there are several sets of quotes involved. Both these developers also use the concatenation operator and String.Builder, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Concerning speed it almost always [doesn't matter](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

```
var answer = "Use what makes " + "the code most easy " + "to read";
```

Comment: Using string concatenation often would produce lots of small objects in memory, which could negative affect garbage collection performance. It is very hard to measure such effect by test from your link, but it could be very big performance issue for large systems with hard performance requirements.

Comment: There is no need to account for such performance issues before they actually occur. Unless code is used in some very tight loop, it just doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use string.Format when I've chaining together more than 2 or 3 values, as it makes it easier to see what the final result would look like. Concatenating the strings is slow, as you need to create a new string object for each operation.

If you need to join more than 5 strings, use StringBuilder as it would be much faster.

Comment: I propose String.Concat uses StringBuilder so I think that performance argument fails here

Comment: Indeed. If the argument is about relative performance of `Concat` and `Format` then `Concat` will win every time, unless you're doing something insane.

Answer (score 3):

Performance considerations are often the driver behind this decision. See [this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/07/06/The-truth-about-string-concatenation-performance.aspx) article by Ayende.

Answer (score 3):

I normally go for readability, and would tend towards using **Format**. Most code is written once and read multiple times, so making sure the reader can quickly understand what's beening stated is more important (to me).

Answer (score 3):

It is curious, but String.Format internally use StringBuilder.AppendFormat(). For example, String.Format code is looking like:

```
public static string Format(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
{
  if (format == null || args == null)
   throw new ArgumentNullException((format == null ? "format" : "args"));

  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(format.Length + (args.Length * 8));
  builder.AppendFormat(provider, format, args);
  return builder.ToString();
}
```

More about this you can find [here](http://diditwith.net/2006/11/20/StringFormatAndStringBuilder.aspx). So, why we haven't mentioned here about StringBuilder.AppendFormat()!

Regarding to main point of question:

The key is to pick the best tool for the job.  What do I mean?  Consider these awesome words of wisdom:

```
* Concatenate (+) is best at concatenating. 
* StringBuilder is best when you need to building.
* Format is best at formatting.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommend to store string in code so if you will decide to extract your strings from code  then with String.Format it would be easier to do

Comment: Why not? I appreciate that this can be a problem if you anticipate internationalization, but for many apps this is never a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

This is an article on memory usage for various concatenation methods and compiler optimizations used to generate the IL. [Concatenation methods and optimization issue](http://www.cumps.be/nl/blog/commented/string-concatenation-vs-memory-allocation)

Comment: It's OK to link to the article, but it's better to pull out select information and post it here. If that blog goes away/is moved some day this becomes useless answer.